# Perl : get substring which matches regex error

Tags: regex, perl

I am very new to Perl, so please bear with my simple question:

Here is the sample output:

```
Most successful agents in the Emarket climate are (in order of success):
1.  agent10896761       ($-8008)
2.  flightsandroomsonly     ($-10102)
3.  agent10479475hv     ($-10663)
Most successful agents in the Emarket climate are (in order of success):
1.  agent10896761       ($-7142)
2.  agent10479475hv     ($-8982)
3.  flightsandroomsonly     ($-9124)
```

I am interested only in agent names as well as their corresponding balances, so I am hoping to get the following output:

```
agent10896761       -8008
flightsandroomsonly     -10102
agent10479475hv     -10663
agent10896761       -7142
agent10479475hv     -8982
flightsandroomsonly     -9124
```

For later processes.

This is the code I've got so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
open(MYINPUTFILE, $ARGV[0]);

while(<MYINPUTFILE>)
{
    my($line) = $_;
    chomp($line);

    # regex match test
    if($line =~ m/agent10479475/)
    {   
        if($line =~ m/($-[0-9]+)/)
        {
            print "$1\n";
        }

    }
    if($line =~ m/flightsandroomsonly/)
    {
        print "$line\n";
    }
}
```

The second regex match has nothing wrong, 'cause that is printing out the whole line. However, for the first regex match, I've got some other output such like:

```
$ ./compareResults.pl 3.txt
2.      flightsandroomsonly             ($-10102)
0479475
0479475
3.      flightsandroomsonly             ($-9124)
1.      flightsandroomsonly             ($-8053)
0479475
1.      flightsandroomsonly             ($-6126)
0479475
```

If I "escape" the braces like this

```
if($line =~ m/\($-[0-9]+\)/)
{
    print "$1\n";
}
```

Then there is never a match for the first regex...

So I'm stuck with a problem of making that particular regex work. Any hints for this? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
perl -ane '$F[2]=~s/\(|\)//g;print "$F[1] $F[2]\n" if $F[1]=~/agent|flight/' file
```

Comment: @ghostdog74 : I never imagined to see a one liner solution. wow, thanks for this tip. I can see the logic here.

Answer (score 4):

Remember that `$` in a regular expression is an anchor at the end of the string. Escape it to match a literal dollar-sign character.

I'd write it this way:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

# for demo only
*ARGV = *DATA;

my $agent = qr/
  ^ \s* \d+ \.   # item number at the beginning of line
  \s+
  (\S+)          # agent name into $1
  \s+
  \( \s* \$ \s*  # start of balance
  (-?\d+)        # balance into $2
  \s* \)         # end of balance
  \s* $          # optional whitespace at the tail
/x;
while (<>) {
  if (my ($name,$balance) = /$agent/) {
    printf "%-20s : %d\n", $name, $balance;
  }
}

__DATA__
Most successful agents in the Emarket climate are (in order of success):
1.  agent10896761       ($-8008)
2.  flightsandroomsonly     ($-10102)
3.  agent10479475hv     ($-10663)
Most successful agents in the Emarket climate are (in order of success):
1.  agent10896761       ($-7142)
2.  agent10479475hv     ($-8982)
3.  flightsandroomsonly     ($-9124)
```

Output:

```
agent10896761        : -8008
flightsandroomsonly  : -10102
agent10479475hv      : -10663
agent10896761        : -7142
agent10479475hv      : -8982
flightsandroomsonly  : -9124
```

Don't let the `*ARGV = *DATA` line scare you. That allows me to have the program and its input together in a single file without changing the processing logic. In your code, you'd remove that line and then run your program in the same way as before, *e.g.*,

```
$ ./compareResults.pl input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while(<DATA>){
    #split on whitespaces, pick 2nd and 3rd items
#check 2nd item matches pattern, do some trimming to 3rd
#store them to @data and print them
    my @data =grep{/\w{13,}/ || s/\(\$|\)//g;}((split' ')[1,2]);
    print join("\t",@data),"\n" if (@data);

}


__DATA__
1.  agent10896761       ($-8008)
2.  flightsandroomsonly     ($-10102)
3.  agent10479475hv     ($-10663)
Most successful agents in the Emarket climate are (in order of success):
1.  agent10896761       ($-7142)
2.  agent10479475hv     ($-8982)
3.  flightsandroomsonly     ($-9124)
```

---

```
__OUTPUT__
agent10896761   -8008
flightsandroomsonly     -10102
agent10479475hv -10663
agent10896761   -7142
agent10479475hv -8982
flightsandroomsonly     -9124
```

Comment: @Mike  : thanks for this tip, seems most likely the way that I am gonna learn from uni.